# Strategies for not having my boat tridented into the soup

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Sometime in the past, Mojang added boats with chests... this makes it even more important.

But basically, the drowned shut down all boat travel everywhere. In large oceans I can usually survive by noticing underwater ruins and simply avoiding them before I come within spawning range... but rivers seem to be impassable.

It seems like the boat is instantly destroyed 50% of the time, but the rest it will take a second shot. These come in much too quickly for the warning to have been any help... 1.5-2 seconds afterward. I do not stop or slow down, hoping to outrun the second shot, but likely I am directly overhead with the first shot and the second therefor is still going to be at close range.

If I managed to get armored up by that point in the game, I can survive maybe as many as 4 or 5 hits. But this always seems to be not nearly enough. Swimming to shore can take far longer than the 7.5 seconds I have before I am dead, and doesn't even put me out of the danger zone if there is no cover on the river bank or shore.

I play in large biomes, so I think the rivers are much wider (they seem to be... this is good for the most part, they were often unnavigable in non-large-biomes). I play hardcore, so this is discouraging, I'll often wait several weeks before starting another game.

Personally, I think Mojang really screwed up with the drowned and their tridents, they're unbalanced to a degree that is absurd. I don't mind dying (that's what makes the game fun), but there don't seem to be any strategies that mitigate this failure mode other than:

- Stay on land, always
- Absurd levels of powering up (Protection 4 netherite with hot-barred potions) that are impractical or impossible without boating

Is there a better way to play, some technique or strategy, that will allow me to continue without this frustration? All 3 of my games started in the last two months have ended in this fashion, and there seems little that can be done about it.

Comment: Hey John O, would it be possible to edit your question down to the essential parts? Personally, I find this post to be bordering on a rant, and it makes it harder to answer when people have to dig through a bunch of opinion. I took a crack at editing it down, but I ended up removing a lot from your post and it didn't sit right with me. At the very least, please consider rewording the last section of your post to be a stand-alone question--perhaps in bold?

Comment: @Schism If it's that bad, I can delete it. But when I edit it down to the question in other stack exchanges, they tell me that that's bad and then delete it anyway. I sort of feel damned-if-I-do-damned-if-I-don't. A "how do I avoid this" without the rest is "just play the game differently" except that form of play is unappealing.

Comment: @JohnO "Swimming to shore can take far longer than the 7.5 seconds I have before I am dead" why? If you keep moving the tridents won't hit you.

Comment: @justhalf The tridents never seem to miss. With skeletons, I can zig and zag. But tridents never miss, even when I'm on land... only finding cover (since they're in the water, backing up far enough from the shore can do the trick) works. When in the water, neither sinking nor swimming to the top, neither swimming slow/fast, nothing works. I'm just dead.

Comment: Huh, interesting. I just swim straight and it never hits. Don't swim completely at the surface (where you bob up and down from going out and into the water), but just at the border so you can breathe but still not going out of the water.

Comment: @justhalf Would it be possible to post a video of this somewhere? I *think* I know what you're describing, but I can't be far off of that and it seems they nail me every attempt. Perhaps I'm just slightly off on the water depth or something. I sometimes try swimming under (I usually have the magic helmet, so staying submerged for a bit is no big deal), and that never works either. If there's some variation I'm just not discovering on my own that does this, it would be the exact answer I'm looking for.